# Populating a listView using a custom adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am attempting to create a listview populated with messages using a custom adapter for my Fragment. My android project runs with no problem or errors. I can see that messages are properly being passed into the constructor. I don't think my getView is ever being called though, and I am under the belief it happens automatically. I put prints inside the getView of the adapter, but they never go off.

Here is my MessageAdapter

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<message>  {

private final Context context;
private final int layoutResourceId;
private final ArrayList<message> messages;


public MessageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<message> messages) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder  holder = null;
    int direction = messages.get(i).userType;
    //show message on left or right, depending on if
    //it's incoming or outgoing
    System.out.println("try this");
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); 

        int res = 0;
        if (direction == 0) {
            res = R.layout.message_right;
        } else if (direction == 1) {
            res = R.layout.message_left;
        }

        row = inflater.inflate(res, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }

     System.out.println(messages.get(i).message);
     holder.txtMessage.setText(messages.get(i).message);
     holder.txtDate.setText(messages.get(i).time);

     return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtMessage;
    TextView txtDate;
}
```

}

And here is where I call my adapter in my Fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    View messagesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)messagesView.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);

    ArrayList<message> messages = getMessages();

    MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.listMessages, messages);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
```

Edit: 
As requested get messages.

```
    String[] messageArray = getMessages(); // get messages returns an array of json encoded rows from the db

    for(int i=0; i<messageArray.length; i++) {
        String theMess = null, time = null;
        int userType = 0;

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(messageArray[i]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {theMess = jsonObject.getString("message");} catch (JSONException e) {}
        try {time = jsonObject.getString("time");} catch (JSONException e) {}
        try {userType = jsonObject.getInt("userType");} catch (JSONException e) {}

        message newMessage = new message(theMess, time, userType);
        messages.add(newMessage);   
    }
```

Comment: You should probably using `Log`s instead of `System.out` and still should give breakpoints a try.

Comment: Post your getMessages method

Comment: Edited in the post. The getMessages() function returns a valid array of messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing getSize method. Once you add getsize and getItem method this will work as expected

Comment: I just added both:  
public int getSize() {
   return messages.size();
}
public message getItem(int i) {
   return messages.get(i);
}

And I am still getting an empty screen. Is there a specific way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Also you will have to add view to viewgroup in getview() method.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
super(context, layoutResourceId);
```

to

```
super(context, layoutResourceId, messages);
```

You don't need `getCount()` or `getItem()`. Unless you need your own special logic, `ArrayAdapter` already has implementations for them that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your `ArrayList<message> messages`, the `ArrayAdapter` already maintains it's own `ArrayList`. You should pass your messages to the super ctr, and use `getItem(position)` in the `getView` method.